# Unhandled promise rejection: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise : Angular

Tags: angular, firefox, angular8, package.json

Application works like a charm with Chrome. But with edge and Firefox its throwing this error

```
Error: "Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise 
api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)"
```

I found similar questions here but solution was changing the order of `core.js` and `zone.js` imports.
I don't have core.js imports in my application.

In `polyfill.js` I have `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'` nothing else.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "DFS_Poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.11.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.1.2",
    "dataframe-js": "^1.4.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.118",
    "@types/vis": "^4.21.19",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Moving `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` statement from `polyfill.js` to `main.js` fixed the issue.

Comment: You're a genius, my friend. Now it's working on my localhost, but still not on the live site...